# Как получить конкретное значение массива php?

Tags: php, массивы, json, telegram, бот

Имеется вот такой json ответ

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": {
        "total_count": 14,
        "photos": [[{
            "file_id": "AgADAgAD6qcxGwyaYxMulue7xCVvITMmrQ4ABKwFQfa_ML0d0qQBAAEC",
            "file_size": 4367,
            "width": 160,
            "height": 160
        },
        {
            "file_id": "AgADAgAD6qcxGwyaYxMulue7xCVvITMmrQ4ABBYsR-VFYPb806QBAAEC",
            "file_size": 14094,
            "width": 320,
            "height": 320
        },
        {
            "file_id": "AgADAgAD6qcxGwyaYxMulue7xCVvITMmrQ4ABOlO5fHuDpog1KQBAAEC",
            "file_size": 47984,
            "width": 640,
            "height": 640
        }]]
    }
}
```

У меня есть вот такая функция

```
function getUserProfilePhotos($chat_id) {
    $photo_array = json_decode(file_get_contents($GLOBALS['api'] . '/getUserProfilePhotos?user_id=' . $chat_id . '&limit=1'), TRUE);
    $photo_id = $photo_array['result']['photos'][1]['file_id'];
    return $photo_id;
}
```

Как мне сделать чтобы при обращении к ней она возвращала третий в списке file_id, их там несколько, нужен именно третий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$photo_id = $photo_array['result']['photos'][0][2]['file_id'];
```

Comment: да, спасибо! работает

Comment: @ajaxxx не за что. Отметьте ответ как принятый(галочка слева сверху) ^_^